# derivative of function with norm

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $x, r \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
There is function $\eta(x, r):=A  \frac{1}{\| x-r \|^p}$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

How can I compute derivative of $\eta$ wrt. x?

Comment: Maybe it will help you to write $\tfrac{1}{\|x-r\|^p} = \|x-r\|^{-p} = \big(\sum(x_i-r_i)^2\big)^{-p/2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $||x|| = \langle x, x\rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}$ - note that the scalar product is bilinear, so the derivative of its square with respect to $x$ in direction $v$, ($D_x(v) ||x||$ - the notiation being admittedly a bit clumsy) is given by
$$D_x(v) \langle x- r, x-r \rangle = 2 \langle x-r, v\rangle$$ Applying the chain and product rule you get

\begin{eqnarray} 
D_x(v) A\frac{1}{||x-r||^p} & = & D_x(v) A\langle x-r, x-r\rangle^{-p/2} \\
& = & - p \frac{ \langle x-r, v\rangle}{||x-r||^{p+1}}A
\end{eqnarray}
(If you want to know the derivative wrt to $x_i$ just set $v= e_i$).

(I'm not sure what the intention is of having the matrix $A$. Since it does not depend on $x$ it just behaves like a constant, though).

Answer (score 0):

Since the function returns a matrix,
and you want to differentiate it with
respect to a vector, you will obtain
a third-order tensor.

Consider the scalar
$u = \| \mathbf{x-r} \|$
so that
$\eta_{ij}
= \frac{A_{ij}}{u^p}$.

The differential writes
$$
d\eta_{ij}
= -p \frac{A_{ij}}{u^{p+1}} du
$$.

Furthermore
$d(u^2) = 2 u du = 
2 (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r})^T d\mathbf{x}
$.

Isolating $du$ and replacing it in the previous expression yields the derivative
$$
\frac{\partial \eta_{ij}}{\partial x_k}
=
-\frac{p}{\| \mathbf{x-r} \|^{p+2}} 
\left( x_k-r_k \right) A_{ij}
$$